# Java generics - incompatible types

Tags: java, generics

Just need some help with this error in code:

```
interface ParticleId{
    int getX();
}

class ParticleId1 implements ParticleId{
    int a;
    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return a;
    }
}

class ParticleId2 implements ParticleId{
    int a,b;
    @Override
    public int getX() {
        return a+b;
    }
}

interface ParticleInt<K extends ParticleId, O extends ParticleInt<K, O>>{
    O withSmt();
}

class Particle<K extends ParticleId> implements ParticleInt<K, Particle<K>>{
    @Override
    public Particle<K> withSmt() {
        return new Particle<>();
    }
}

class Particle2<K extends ParticleId> extends Particle<K>{
    @Override
    public Particle2<K> withSmt() {
        return new Particle2<>();
    }
}

interface Executable<P extends Particle<? extends ParticleId>>{
    void setExecutableStrategy(ExecutableStrategy<P> s);
}

interface ExecutableStrategy<P extends Particle<? extends ParticleId>>{
    Stream<P> exec(List<P> l);
}

class Particle2Strat implements ExecutableStrategy<Particle2<? extends ParticleId>>{
    @Override
    public Stream<Particle2<? extends ParticleId>> exec(List<Particle2<? extends ParticleId>> l) {
        return l.stream().map(x -> x.withSmt());
    }
}

class ParticleStrat<P extends Particle<? extends ParticleId>> implements ExecutableStrategy<P>{
    @Override
    public Stream<P> exec(List<P> l) {
        return l.stream().map(x -> x.withSmt());
        // [44,38] incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds
        // equality constraints: P
        // [ERROR] lower bounds: Particle<capture#1 of ? extends ParticleId>
    }
}
```

The error is shown on the end of the code, and exact description is `[44,38] incompatible types: inference variable R has incompatible bounds. equality constraints: P. [ERROR] lower bounds: Particle<capture#1 of ? extends ParticleId>`.

Quick fix that I found working is just manually casting lambda to (P) like `(P)x.withSmt()`. Anybody knows more proper way to fix this if possible at all?

I just updated the code so it is not using anymore `Integer` but `ParticleId` interface.

**UPDATE**

After update I now have this problem:

```
class ParticleStrat<P extends ParticleId> implements ExecutableStrategy<Particle<P>>{
    @Override
    public Stream<Particle<P>> exec(List<Particle<P>> l) {
        return l.stream().map(x -> x.withSmt());  //OK NOW
    }
}

class MainExecutable<P extends Particle<? extends ParticleId>> implements Executable<P>{

    private ExecutableStrategy<P> s;

    public MainExecutable() {
        this.s = new ParticleStrat<>();
        //incompatible types: cannot infer type arguments for ParticleStrat<>
        //no instance(s) of type variable(s) P exist so that ParticleStrat<P> conforms to ExecutableStrategy<P>
    }

    @Override
    public void setExecutableStrategy(ExecutableStrategy<P> s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: `Integer` is a final class. `K extends Integer` is meaningless.

Comment: Yes. I use this just for demonstration.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the declaration of `ParticleStrat` class to the following solves the compilation error:

```
class ParticleStrat<P extends ParticleInt<P>> implements ExecutableStrategy<P>{
    @Override
    public Stream<P> exec(List<P> l) {
        return l.stream().map(x -> x.withSmt());
    }
}
```

This way `x.withSmt()` is guaranteed to return `P`.

EDIT following the change in your question:

This passes compilation:

```
class ParticleStrat<K extends Integer> implements ExecutableStrategy<Particle<K>>{
    @Override
    public Stream<Particle<K>> exec(List<Particle<K>> l) {
        return l.stream().map(x -> x.withSmt());
    }
}
```

And after your latest update:

```
class ParticleStrat<K extends ParticleId> implements ExecutableStrategy<Particle<K>>{
    @Override
    public Stream<Particle<K>> exec(List<Particle<K>> l) {
        return l.stream().map(x -> x.withSmt());
    }
}
```

As for your latest problem, the same approach can work:

```
class MainExecutable<K extends ParticleId> implements Executable<Particle<K>>{

    private ExecutableStrategy<Particle<K>> s;

    public MainExecutable() {
        this.s = new ParticleStrat<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void setExecutableStrategy(ExecutableStrategy<Particle<K>> s) {
        this.s = s;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. that works easily. Can you please check my updated code where I added additional generics to reflect closely my real problem? I suppose this is more-less similar?

Comment: @bojanv55 `K extends Integer` and `? extends Integer` make no sense, since Integer is final. Perhaps you should come up with some code that makes more sense.

Comment: sorry, just added Integer in a hurry (in real code it is an actual object) . If this is actual problem i'll update code acordingly.

Comment: Your code works also for my newest updated example. But when I try to init the class of this I have a problem. (Updated code sample). Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Eran. But what if I don't need exact ParticleId type in the code? I mostly use it in this classes for equality check. Do I still need to bubble it up the chain, or there is some other tactics I could use?